# Two formulas in the same cell in Apple's Numbers

Tags: ms-office, numbers

[image]

In Apple's Numbers, I have a table which calculates GAP between two values in two rows (red), I would like even to calculate gap between calculated values in the same cell (blue), is it possible?

Comment: ∂(98->60 )=-38! Or what's the meaning of -28?

Comment: oops... I made a mistake!